# непредвиденный конец файла во время поиска предкомпилированного заголовка

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Здравствуйте, имеется следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int Func();

int main() {
    Func();
    return 0;
}

int Func(){
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
    cout << "2+2 = " << 2 + 2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Однако при выполнении выдает ошибку:

> c:\users\ok\source\repos\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4.cpp(15): fatal error C1010: непредвиденный конец файла во время поиска предкомпилированного заголовка. Возможно, вы забыли добавить директиву "#include "stdafx.h"" в источник.

Добавляю #include "stdafx.h", все равно выдает ошибку:

> 1>c:\users\ok\source\repos\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4.cpp(12): error C2065: cout: необъявленный идентификатор
>   1>c:\users\ok\source\repos\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4.cpp(12): error C2065: endl: необъявленный идентификатор
>   1>c:\users\ok\source\repos\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4.cpp(13): error C2065: cout: необъявленный идентификатор
>   1>c:\users\ok\source\repos\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4.cpp(13): error C2065: endl: необъявленный идентификатор

Comment: Поскольку вы не используете stdafx.h в коде - следует отменить Precompiled Headers option в настройках проекта

Comment: У вас в коде несколько ошибок. Когда вы исправили первую (добавили stdafx.h), проявилась вторая. Исправляйте и её тоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании нового проекта вы выбрали "Консольное приложение". По умолчанию в нем есть "stdafx.h". Предлагаю выбирать "Пустой проект" и в нем писать с нуля. В том случае, если хотите оставить этот проект и исправить его, то поставьте #include "stdafx.h" в самый верх, до остальных директив include. Можно все include записать в него, и тогда будет быстрее компилироваться.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можете отключить "предварительно откомпилированный заголовок".
Зайдите в Проект -> Свойства ->

[image: Путь где изменить параметры]